# How to fix `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync

Tags: npm, heroku

I've tried pretty much everything I can find on google including `npm i`, deleting `package.lock` and running `npm i` again, re-cloning the project, changing the buildback, specifying previous node versions.

I keep getting this error. How can I resolve it?

```
`npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.7.4 from lock file
```

I don't see that dependency listed anywhere in my project.

here is my main package.json file inside my client dir:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.1",
    "@chec/commerce.js": "^2.8.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@inlightmedia/react-countdown-timer": "^1.1.2",
    "@nilevia/count-down-timer-react": "^1.0.4",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-firebase/database": "^0.3.11",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.29.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "add2calendar": "^1.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^5.6.0",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.4.1",
    "moralis": "^1.3.1",
    "ngrok": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-google-places-autocomplete": "^3.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-moralis": "^1.3.1",
    "react-open-app": "^1.0.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
    "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
    "stripe": "^8.194.0",
    "use-react-countdown": "^1.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "ngrok": "ngrok"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

here is one package.json file in my ethers dir:

```
{
  "name": "smart_constracts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "harleauxcarrera",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.4",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "hardhat": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

And here is one package.json at the root of my project dir :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.1",
    "@chec/commerce.js": "^2.8.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.4.2",
    "framer-motion": "^5.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-open-app": "^1.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "use-react-countdown": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm start --prefix client"
  }
}
```

Here are the build packs I am using :

1. https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

and here is the buildpack output:

```
 Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack
remote:        2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
remote: -----> Subdir buildpack app detected
remote: -----> Subdir buildpack in client
remote:        creating cache: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache
remote:        created tmp dir: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirXYvgi
remote:        moving working dir: client to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirXYvgi
remote:        cleaning build dir /tmp/build_155f5cac
remote:        copying preserved work dir from cache /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirXYvgi to build dir /tmp/build_155f5cac
remote:        cleaning tmp dir /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/subdirXYvgi
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```

I was previoulsy using this buildpack:
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
for create-react-app but the terminal stated it had reached it's end of life so I had to switch it out for :https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that I tried that (npm i, npm install) as well

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `package.json` file. Heroku thinks it asks for TypeScript to be installed. Also, do you have more than one `package.json`?

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris. 
have edited the question. 

I do have more than one package.json file that live outside the /client dir of my app. ( have tried npm install that one two )

Comment: Please add all of your `package.json` files.

Comment: Gotcha. I was under the impression that it was only the main package.json in my client dir that was giving issues

Comment: Where would that dependency typescript be coming from @Chris?

Comment: Nothing obvious... can you edit in more context for the error message?

Comment: There's not much else going on besides those two error lines. 

I was deploying with heroku last week until this issue happened and not sure what is causing it

Comment: one of the buildpacks I was using for create-react-app was stated to be at end of life so I had to switch that out for a different one, maybe this is an issue

Comment: What buildpacks are you using? Please show the output of `heroku buildpacks`.

Comment: added more buildpack details

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Chris can u help resolve please

Comment: Check my answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618153/10403061

Answer (score 4):

I run to your issue when I was searching for answer to mine anyway, I just deleted the `package-lock.json` file and tried to deploy it again and it worked