# Firebase Deployment Error: Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions, npm-install

I am currently working with Firebase hosting but suddenly faced deployment errors. I tried all possible solutions but deployment errors were getting multiple times. So now requires community help. Please help me to solve this problem.

From This line deployment process failed

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function firebase-frameworks-softwares-techy:ssrsoftwarestechy(us-central1)...
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's ajv@8.12.0 does not satisfy ajv@6.12.6
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ajv@8.12.0 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-03-18T17_41_51_146Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: ...c-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: error-ex@1.3.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: lines-and-columns@1.2.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: find-up@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-core-module@2.11.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: resolve-from@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@2.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: argparse@1.0.10 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: cliui@8.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yargs-parser@21.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-03-18T17_41_49_788Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
✔  functions[firebase-frameworks-softwares-techy:ssrsoftwarestechy(us-central1)] Successful update operation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        api(us-central1)
        api-app:helloWorld(us-central1)
Function URL (firebase-frameworks-softwares-techy:ssrsoftwarestechy(us-central1)): https://ssrsoftwarestechy-llk2uv2hmq-uc.a.run.app
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function api in region us-central1
- Error Failed to update function helloWorld in region us-central1
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `helloWorld` function you attempted to deploy looks like a test function. If so and you're just learning GCF, I'd recommend just recreating the entire project. It appears you may have missed a step. You may even want to start from zero and make sure everything is properly installed using the official Google docs.

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that you used some flag to generate `package.json` or `package-lock.json` that now `npm ci` does not detect in firebase and there is a mismatch.

For example, you could have

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

inside your `.npmrc` file in your local computer when generating the files, in which case you would need to run `npm ci --legacy-peer-deps` for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

Delete **package-lock.json**

Then try to redeploy your project `firebase deploy`

NB: this solution is not ideal but that's the only thing that's working for me at the moment